# Start each longtable on new page

Tags: positioning, longtable, two-column, appendices, clearpage

I'm working on a two-column document of type `{revtex4-1}`. For the appendix I have several longtables (longtable*) that each span over more than one page. I would like to start every table on the top of a new page. But neither `\clearpage` nor `\newpage` do what I want.

An example:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Configuration %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass[aps,prl,twocolumn,
preprintnumbers,
amsmath,amssymb,showkeys,floatfix,nofootinbib,reprint]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[outdir=./]{epstopdf}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{longtable}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
\usepackage{diagbox} 

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

% Any configuration that should be done before the end of the preamble:
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue}


\begin{document}
 Hola, aquí encuentra el abstract. abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract
abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract

\begin{appendices}


\LTcapwidth=\textwidth
\begin{longtable*}[t!]{|P{1.1cm}|P{1.24cm}|P{1.24cm}|P{1.24cm}|P{1.24cm}|P{1.24cm}|P{1.24cm}|P{1.24cm}|P{1.24cm}|P{1.24cm}|P{1.24cm}|P{1.24cm}|P{1.24cm}|}

\hline
      $^{6}_{3}\text{ZU}$ &         1.7e-11 &         1.9e+02 &         4.7e+10 &         3.3e-1 &         3.8e+01 &         1.5e+10 &       2.0e-13 &       8.3e+05 &       9.4se+01 &       1.8e-1 &       3.1e+01 &       8.3e-09 \\
\hline \end{longtable*}




\clearpage
\LTcapwidth=\textwidth
\begin{longtable*}[p]{|P{1.1cm}|P{1.24cm}|P{1.24cm}|P{1.24cm}|P{1.24cm}|P{1.24cm}|P{1.24cm}|P{1.24cm}|P{1.24cm}|P{1.24cm}|P{1.24cm}|P{1.24cm}|P{1.24cm}|}
\hline
$^{7}_{3}\text{ZI}$ &         1.0e-01 &         1.4e+03 &         4.9e-11 &         3.3e-12 &         3.8e+02 &         1.5e+11 &       2.0e-12 &       2.8e+05 &       1.4e+10 &       1.8e-16 &       3.8e+02 &       8.3e+19 \\
\hline\end{longtable*}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: why doesn't `\clearpage` do what you want?

Comment: It doesnt change anything

Comment: Please include a complete minimal working example that demonstrates that shows what you tried so far and how `\clearpage` does not work.

Comment: `\clearpage` always forces a new page unless you have some rather strange code to stop that, please (always) include a complete small document that shows the issue. But also `longtable` doesn't support two column, so you may want `\onecolumn` rather than `\clearpage`

Comment: sorry it's longtable*

Comment: without an example impossible to comment on your main question, but commenting on your preamble, you probably don't need to load `epstopdf` , you don't need to specify `graphicx` twice, you probably don't need `dblfloatfix`, and `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` looks rather odd  setting unless you increase `\parskip` elsewhere?

Comment: Ok so I updated my question. The tables are now very small though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

revtex appears to have disabled the standard `\onecolumn` command but provides `\onecolumngrid`

```
\documentclass[aps,prl,twocolumn,
preprintnumbers,
amsmath,amssymb,showkeys,floatfix,nofootinbib,reprint]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[outdir=./]{epstopdf}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{longtable}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
\usepackage{diagbox} 

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

% Any configuration that should be done before the end of the preamble:
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue}


\begin{document}
 Hola, aquí encuentra el abstract. abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract
abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract

\onecolumngrid

\begin{appendices}



\LTcapwidth=\textwidth
\begin{longtable*}[t!]{|P{1.1cm}|P{1.24cm}|P{1.24cm}|P{1.24cm}|P{1.24cm}|P{1.24cm}|P{1.24cm}|P{1.24cm}|P{1.24cm}|P{1.24cm}|P{1.24cm}|P{1.24cm}|P{1.24cm}|}

\hline
      $^{6}_{3}\text{ZU}$ &         1.7e-11 &         1.9e+02 &         4.7e+10 &         3.3e-1 &         3.8e+01 &         1.5e+10 &       2.0e-13 &       8.3e+05 &       9.4se+01 &       1.8e-1 &       3.1e+01 &       8.3e-09 \\
\hline \end{longtable*}




\clearpage
\LTcapwidth=\textwidth
\begin{longtable*}[p]{|P{1.1cm}|P{1.24cm}|P{1.24cm}|P{1.24cm}|P{1.24cm}|P{1.24cm}|P{1.24cm}|P{1.24cm}|P{1.24cm}|P{1.24cm}|P{1.24cm}|P{1.24cm}|P{1.24cm}|}
\hline
$^{7}_{3}\text{ZI}$ &         1.0e-01 &         1.4e+03 &         4.9e-11 &         3.3e-12 &         3.8e+02 &         1.5e+11 &       2.0e-12 &       2.8e+05 &       1.4e+10 &       1.8e-16 &       3.8e+02 &       8.3e+19 \\
\hline\end{longtable*}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```